# iphone intercept link

Tags: ios, uiwebview, hyperlink, youtube, intercept

i have an app that intercepts a link in a uiwebview,  but I want to get that link string [you tube link] to start the player ,

- I have the youtube player working with a hardcoded url, [opening in a modal view]
- and have the url path once the link is tapped from the web site, going to a string

but havent figured out yet how to stop the uiwebview from going to the pressed link, getting the link string and opening my modal view with the player

If I use

> webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest

```
retun NO
```

the link gets invisible,

so how to accomplish this?

thanks!